# Arch Linux: Steam Not Starting After Update (x86_64 Extra Nvidia 384.69-2)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia, steam

I'm having this issue on my system only after the nvidia update.

The error I get is

```
/home/????/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 154: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
/home/????/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 154: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
Running Steam on arch  64-bit
/home/????/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 154: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
```

Also when running "steam-native" I get:

```
/home/????/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 154: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
/home/????/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 154: VERSION_ID: unbound variable
Running Steam on arch  64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is disabled by the user
```

Which isn't much different.

I suspect it has something to do with there updated drive.

Answer (score 1):

It has indeed to do with drivers.

lib32-nvidia-utils from multilib wasn't moved in from [testing] in time with the rest of nvidia drivers in extra. It is updated now, so you can either wait for your mirror to sync the changes in and then update lib32-nvidia-utils or you update it manually by downloading from a mirror and using `pacman -U`.

See https://www.archlinux.org/packages/multilib/x86_64/lib32-nvidia-utils/

Comment: Thank you, I found this page which helped me resolve the issue, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229697